# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 132

Tags: java

I am trying to make a game and at this stage all it does is create a board of tiles which you can remove or place. However when I extend the grid to any value that is above 128, it crashes. However it only happens if the width is the bigger number. If the height is bigger then it makes a second grid below the first one and it gets kinda weird. Below is my code and the stack trace of the error I get.

You can see how it's supposed to function by changing the values in the world settings under `Game.java`. (Again, if width is the bigger number and it multiplies to over 128 that's what causes the error.)

Game.java

```java
package engine;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel{
    private Thread thread;
    
    //world settings
    static int worldWidth = 11;
    static int worldHeight = 12;
    
    public int w = worldWidth;
    public int h = worldHeight;
    
    //window settings
    private static int windowWidth = 800;
    private static int windowHeight = 600;
    private static String windowTitle = "Game";
    
    //tile settings
    public static int tileSize = 50;
    
    public static int tilex;
    public static int tiley;
    
    private static byte[] tiles;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //set background color
        setBackground(new Color(0,128,255));

        //set color and area of shape
        g.setColor(new Color(0,255,0));
        
        //checks array every repaint for modified tiles
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                int i = y + (x * w);
                if (tiles[i] == 1) {
                    tilex = x * tileSize;
                    tiley = y * tileSize;
                    g.fillRect(tilex, tiley, tileSize, tileSize);
                }
            }
        }
        //Pointer/selector
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Game();
    }
    
    public void init() {
        new Window(windowWidth, windowHeight, windowTitle, this);
        Window.running = true;
        
        thread = new Thread();
        thread.start();
        
        generate();
    }
    
    public void terminate() {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    public Game() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            init();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString(), "Failed to start " + windowTitle, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        while(Window.running) {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            //closes game if escape is pressed or if window is closed (handled in window class)
            if (!Window.running) {
                System.out.println("Closing " + windowTitle);
                terminate();
            }
            //render
            repaint();
        }
    }
    
    public void generate() {
        tiles = new byte[w * h];
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                int i = y + (x * w);
                //1 = tile present, 0 = not present
                tiles[i] = (byte) 1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void changeSquare() {
        if (GameListener.mouseButton == 3 && GameListener.modifyBlock) {
            tiles[GameListener.byteToModify] = 1;
        } else if (GameListener.mouseButton == 1 && GameListener.modifyBlock){
            tiles[GameListener.byteToModify] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Window.java

```java
package engine;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window {
    public static boolean running = false;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
        //creates and displays window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        
        KeyListener keylistener = new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                GameListener.keyListener(keyEvent);
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                
            }
        };
        
        MouseListener mouselistener = new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                GameListener.mouseListener(mouseEvent);
                Game.changeSquare();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                
            }
        };
        
        MouseMotionListener mousemotionlistener = new MouseMotionListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent mouseMotionEvent) {
                GameListener.mouseMotionListener(mouseMotionEvent);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
                
            }
        };

        //listens for window close and sends back to game loop to terminate
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                running = false;
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().addKeyListener(keylistener);
        frame.getContentPane().addMouseListener(mouselistener);
        frame.getContentPane().addMouseMotionListener(mousemotionlistener);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and finally GameListener.java

```java
package engine;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class GameListener {
    private static int tileX;
    private static int tileY;
    private static int xTries;
    private static int yTries;
    
    private static int tileXM;
    private static int tileYM;
    private static int xTriesM;
    private static int yTriesM;

    public static int byteToModify;
    public static int mouseButton;
    public static boolean modifyBlock;
    
    public static boolean drawSelector;
    public static int byteToDrawSelector;
    
    public static void keyListener(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        
        //put key if statements here (for example escape to close
        
        //use for testing key name when adding a new if statement 
        //String character = KeyEvent.getKeyText(code);
        //System.out.println("Character: " + KeyEvent.getKeyText(code));
        //System.out.println("Code: " + code);
        
        //get key codes at keycode.info
        
        //closes game on escape
        if (code == 27) {
            //escape
            Window.running = false;
        }
        //movement
       // if (code == 87) {
            //W
        //  Game.y = Game.y - 100;
  //      }
      //  if (code == 65) {
            //A
       //   Game.x = Game.x - 100;
      //  }
      //  if (code == 83) {
            //S
       //   Game.y = Game.y + 100;
      //  }
       // if (code == 68) {
            //D
            //Game.x = Game.x + 100;
       // }
    }
    
    public static void mouseListener(MouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println(e.getX());
        //System.out.println(e.getY());
        //System.out.println(e.getButton());
        
        xTries = 0;
        tileX = 0;
        yTries = 0;
        tileY = 0;
        modifyBlock = true;
        
        if (e.getX() < Game.tileSize) {
            
        } else if (e.getX() > Game.tileSize && e.getX() < (Game.tileSize * Game.worldWidth)) {
            for (int i = Game.tileSize; i<e.getX(); i = i + Game.tileSize) {
                xTries++;
            }
            //System.out.println(xTries);
            tileX = xTries;
        } else {
            System.err.println("User clicked outside of world");
            modifyBlock = false;
        }
        if (e.getY() < Game.tileSize) {
        } else if (e.getY() > Game.tileSize && e.getY() < (Game.tileSize * Game.worldHeight)) {
            for (int i = Game.tileSize; i<e.getY(); i = i + Game.tileSize) {
                yTries++;
            }
            //System.out.println(yTries);
            tileY = yTries;
        } else {
            System.err.println("User clicked outside of world");
            modifyBlock = false;
        }
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            mouseButton = 1;
        } else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
            mouseButton = 3;
        }
        byteToModify = tileY+(tileX * Game.worldWidth);
        
        //System.out.println(tileX);
        //System.out.println(tileY);
        //System.out.println(byteToModify);
    }
    
    public static void mouseMotionListener(MouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println(e.getX());
        //System.out.println(e.getY());

        xTriesM = 0;
        tileXM = 0;
        yTriesM = 0;
        tileYM = 0;
        drawSelector = true;
        
        if (e.getX() < Game.tileSize) {
            
        } else if (e.getX() > Game.tileSize && e.getX() < (Game.tileSize * Game.worldWidth)) {
            for (int i = Game.tileSize; i<e.getX(); i = i + Game.tileSize) {
                xTriesM++;
            }
            //System.out.println(xTries);
            tileXM = xTriesM;
        } else {
            drawSelector = false;
        }
        if (e.getY() < Game.tileSize) {
        } else if (e.getY() > Game.tileSize && e.getY() < (Game.tileSize * Game.worldHeight)) {
            for (int i = Game.tileSize; i<e.getY(); i = i + Game.tileSize) {
                yTriesM++;
            }
            //System.out.println(yTries);
            tileYM = yTriesM;
        } else {
            drawSelector = false;
        }
        byteToDrawSelector = tileYM+(tileXM* Game.worldWidth);
    }
}
```

And here's the error I get when I load the game.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 132
    at engine.Game.paint(Game.java:45)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 132
    at engine.Game.paint(Game.java:45)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It says the problem is in `Game.java` line 45 but I really don't understand what could be causing this.

Comment: You override method `paint`, in class `Game` and the first line in the method is `super.paintComponent()`. Is that your actual code? Maybe you made a mistake when you copied your code to your question? Also, which line is line 45 in file `Game.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations in your `for` loops are wrong.

Firstly, `w` (the member variable in class `Game`) actually represents the number of columns in your [two-dimensional] grid of tiles and `h` (another member variable in class `Game`) represents the number of rows. You have these the wrong way around in your nested `for` loops. So instead of

```java
for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
```

you should have

```java
for(int x = 0; x < h; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < w; y++) {
```

So I only changed the code of class `Game`. For the sake of completeness, here is the entire code of the class with the changes described above.

```java
package engine;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel {
    private Thread thread;

    // world settings
    static int worldWidth = 12;
    static int worldHeight = 11;

    public int w = worldWidth;
    public int h = worldHeight;

    // window settings
    private static int windowWidth = 800;
    private static int windowHeight = 600;
    private static String windowTitle = "Game";

    // tile settings
    public static int tileSize = 50;

    public static int tilex;
    public static int tiley;

    private static byte[] tiles;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // set background color
        setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 255));

        // set color and area of shape
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));

        // checks array every repaint for modified tiles
        for (int x = 0; x < h; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < w; y++) {
                int i = y + (x * w);
                if (tiles[i] == 1) {
                    tilex = x * tileSize;
                    tiley = y * tileSize;
                    g.fillRect(tilex, tiley, tileSize, tileSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Game();
    }

    public void init() {
        new Window(windowWidth, windowHeight, windowTitle, this);
        Window.running = true;

        thread = new Thread();
        thread.start();

        generate();
    }

    public void terminate() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public Game() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            init();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString(), "Failed to start " + windowTitle,
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        while (Window.running) {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            // closes game if escape is pressed or if window is closed (handled in window
            // class)
            if (!Window.running) {
                System.out.println("Closing " + windowTitle);
                terminate();
            }
            // render
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void generate() {
        tiles = new byte[w * h];
        for (int x = 0; x < h; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < w; y++) {
                int i = y + (x * w);
                // 1 = tile present, 0 = not present
                tiles[i] = (byte) 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void changeSquare() {
        if (GameListener.mouseButton == 3 && GameListener.modifyBlock) {
            tiles[GameListener.byteToModify] = 1;
        }
        else if (GameListener.mouseButton == 1 && GameListener.modifyBlock) {
            tiles[GameListener.byteToModify] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You should also note that your design contains [circular dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) since each one of the three classes, `Game`, `GameListener` and `Window` references the other two. This is generally a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have line numbers in this display and will not count lines.
Check the code in your line 45. I assume it is

```
if (tiles[i] == 1) {
```

You know that the application is trying to access index 132 when it crashes. Check the size of your array. I guess it is 11x12=132 items, numbered from 0 to 131.

Is it possible your calculation of i is wrong?

Comment: well it worked fine up until it went over 128 array cells, i checked i and it seems right to me although im probably wrong.